# django forms prefetch on cleaned data

Tags: python, django, forms

I am working a improving the amount of database hits my Django application makes, and one of my gripes is with the Django forms.

When I GET a page with a form, it will load objects from the database in order to fill in `ModelChoiceField`s, which is great.

When I POST some form data, the form will clean the data. Now, in my `clean_foo` method of the form, I want to access one of the `foo` objects relations: `foo.bar`. This will hit the database to get the `bar` object.

Is there any way for me to prefetch `bar`? What I mean is that when the form uses the `pk` to find the `foo` object, can I have it prefetch the `bar` as well? Where might I do that?

Looking at the [Django source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L1207-L1215), it seems that the chosen object is fetched directly with `.get()` and not as a queryset with `.filter()`

```
def to_python(self, value):
    if value in self.empty_values:
        return None
    try:
        key = self.to_field_name or 'pk'
        value = self.queryset.get(**{key: value})    # <-- Right here
    except (ValueError, TypeError, self.queryset.model.DoesNotExist):
        raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_choice'], code='invalid_choice')
    return value
```

So, what that tells me is that I am not supposed to try anything there. Best thing I can do is

```
def clean_foo(self):
    foo = Foo.objects.filter(pk=self.cleaned_data['foo'].pk).select_related('bar')
    [...]
```

There I can prefetch what I need for the rest of the logic. So it won't be 1 query, but I can make it at most 2 queries.

I realise this is starting to sound like a statement and not a question, so please just prove me wrong, if possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you could use `select_related` directly in the definition of the queryset for your field:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    my_field = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Foo.objects.select_related('bar'))
```

Comment: oh, right. It actually uses `self.queryset` when getting the object. Oh my, that was simple

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: this is an over-complicated idea, passing a suitable queryset as Daniel suggested is much simpler.

You could subclass `ModelChoiceField` and override `to_python` so that it does `select_related`.

Unless you've got many foreign keys in your form, or many forms on your page, fields, it might not be worth the extra complexity to save one query.

An example could look like

```
class MyModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, *args, select_related=(), prefetch_related=(), **kwargs):
        super(MyModelChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs):
        self._selects = select_related
        self._prefetches = prefetch_related

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value in self.empty_values:
            return None
        try:
            key = self.to_field_name or 'pk'
            values = self.queryset.filter(
                **{key: value}
            ).select_related(
                *self._selects
            ).prefetch_related(
                *self._prefetches
            )
            value = values.first()
        except (ValueError, TypeError, self.queryset.model.DoesNotExist):
            raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_choice'], code='invalid_choice')
        return value
```